# Trino how can the global session language be set?

Tags: presto, trino

How can the default language value be changed in Trino so that it doesn't have to be set for each session via X-Trino-Language?

I've already tried by adjusting the locale for the JVM:

-Duser.country=FR
-Duser.language=fr

And I've also attempted it through the locale settings in the container where Trino is running. Unfortunately, both without success.

I'm using the official Trino Helm Chart; the JVM configs for the coordinatorlook like this:

```
-server
-Xmx2G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-XX:-UseBiasedLocking
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M
-XX:PerMethodRecompilationCutoff=10000
-XX:PerBytecodeRecompilationCutoff=10000
-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=2000000
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UseAESCTRIntrinsics
-Duser.country=FR
-Duser.language=fr
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
```

and for the worker:

```
-server
-Xmx13G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-XX:-UseBiasedLocking
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M
-XX:PerMethodRecompilationCutoff=10000
-XX:PerBytecodeRecompilationCutoff=10000
-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=2000000
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+UseAESCTRIntrinsics
-Duser.country=FR
-Duser.language=fr
```

Comment: This config should work. Can you share the full jvm.config from both worker and coordinator? Have you restarted Trino after the changes? To test can you do command line by running "java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en trino-cli-executable.jar".

Comment: I've modified my question and added the full JVM config.
After editing the configuration, I restarted my containers.